# Modelling Incidents in Survival Analysis

Tags: survival, cox-model, rare-events, cure-models

I'm working with a mixture cure model in a panel dataset covering multiple products across several years. The time-to-event, defined as the duration between the auction start and product sale, is typically very short, often just a few minutes. If a product isn't sold, it's considered "cured." The same product can be sold multiple times (e.g. on same day but also on different days).

A subset of these products experienced an "incident" that is anticipated to influence both the time-to-event and the likelihood of sale for several weeks. I'm seeking guidance on the best approach to model this situation effectively.

Given my background in finance, I was initially thinking of using an event study to study the time-to-event and cure portion around the event. However, I suspect that this method might not be directly applicable to a mixture cure model.

Any suggestions, alternative approaches or references to papers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!